# Converting TrueColor with alpha image to 256 colors with transparency image

Tags: java, image-processing, transparency, java-io

I wrote a java app to capture screen into true color images, make parts of them transparent, and write them to disk as PNG files with transparency using ImageIO. Now to conserve space I am thinking of converting true color images to 8-bit 256 colors images, making one of the colors transparent, and writing them as GIFs to disk.
I was having hard time making that conversion to work. So does anybody have a code spinet how to create 256 transparent image files in Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PNG8 files with alpha transparency as well. It might give files smaller than GIF.

If you can call commandline executable, then you can use [pngquant](http://pngquant.org).

If you want a pure-Java solution, then [Neuquant](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~dekker/NEUQUANT.HTML) has a [Java port](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~dekker/NeuQuant.java), but the Java version is based on old version that doesn't support transparency (it wouldn't be hard to add if you follow changes in [pngnq](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net)).